# How to test Redux action creators

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, axios

I have an action creator, how should i test it with jest ? 
The problem is , i cant even enter Api function , that is why i cant get LOGIN_SUCCESS,
When i check store.getState() it get me only LOGIN_REQUEST and LOGIN_FAILURE

```
const authUser = (login, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST,
  });

  try {
    return await Api('login', 'post', { login, password })
      .then((response) => {
        const { data } = response;
        if (data.error) {
          throw data;
        }
        const { value } = response.data;
        let encoded = [];
        encoded = JSON.parse(Base64.decode(value));
        dispatch({
          type: actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
          payload: {
            encoded,
          },
        });
        return encoded;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.LOGOUT_FAILURE,
      payload: {
        error,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

api.js

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const Api = (path, method, data) => {
  return axios({
    method,
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}${path}`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_TOKEN}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    },
    data,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have is **not** an [action creator](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators). It's mixed with side effects (i.e api calls). Please consider breaking it into smaller pieces for testing to be more simple and short.

Going back, action creators are simply functions that generates actions.

Like so:

```
const loginRequest = () => {
  type: "LOGIN_REQUEST",
  payload: {}
};

const loginSuccess = (encoded) => {
  type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
  payload: {
    encoded
  }
};
```

Then to test it is simply:

```
import { loginRequest, loginSuccess } from "./actions";

it('creates a LOGIN_REQUEST action', () => {
  const expectedAction = {
    type: 'LOGIN_REQUEST',
  }

  expect(loginRequest()).toEqual(expectedAction);
});

it('creates a LOGIN_SUCCESS action', () => {
  const encoded = 'xxxx';
  const expectedAction = {
    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    payload: {
      encoded
    }
  }

  expect(loginSuccess(encoded)).toEqual(expectedAction)
});
```

The goal of testing action creators is to make sure that the generated action is correct / matches what is expected. Testing API calls can be done by mocking or via Redux saga generators.

Comment: Oh, maybe i spend too much time for it, but i cant get how can i change my code and 'simplify it' the main goal of this code that i make dispatch from login page, and allow user auth or not, and according to api answer i can dicided what should i do, can u give me some real examples if u have one ofc

Comment: @Bravis, you can check out [async examples](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async) or [redux saga testing](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html) should you decide to add a middleware.

Comment: ok, ok . but can u tell me how my authUser.js action should look like, if its too havy ?